# prove that $n^\epsilon$/log(n) goes to infinity without derivatives or functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm looking for a way to prove that for every
$\displaystyle{\quad\epsilon\ >\ 0\,,\quad{n^{\epsilon} \over \log\left(\, n\,\right)} \to \infty,\quad}$ treating it only as a sequence, without using functions and derivatives.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Take $n=2^k$ and think little bit.

Comment: hmm... why am I even allowed to do this? won't it prove it only for a specic subsequence of the series?

Comment: @amirbd89 If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit. Thus, if one subsequence diverges...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, it is possible that one subsequence will diverge to infinity but the sequence itself won't, for example: 0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5 ...