# How to prove that $\frac{\ln(n)^k}{n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, for $n$ large and $\forall k \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

In a textbook, I have read that for a given simulation and for n sufficiently large, model A rate of convergence is $\frac{\ln(n)^k}{n} \quad \forall k \geq 1$ while model B rate of convergence is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
The conclusion was that model A converges faster than model B.

While this is easy to check for some values of $n$, I would like to know how to prove it rigorously, ie:

$$\frac{\ln(n)^k}{n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

for large $n$.

Comment: $\ln n < n^\epsilon \ \forall \ \epsilon > 0$. (n should be big)

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242083/proving-n-epsilon-logn-for-sufficiently-large-n

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n := \frac{\ln(n)^k}{n}$ and $b_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Since $a_n, b_n > 0$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0,
$$
you have that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \leq b_n$ for every $n\geq N$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please remind me of the name of this theorem?

Comment: $\lim_n a_n / b_n = 0$ follows from the comparison between $\log$ and powers (see the comment of Mudream). The fact that $a_n \leq b_n$ for $n$ large follows from the definition of limit: if the limit of $a_n/b_n$ is $0$, then $a_n / b_n \leq 1$ for $n$ large.