# Example of a function satisfying specific limit condition

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Let $\epsilon >0$. I am trying to find a function $f(n):\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)=0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon^2} f(n)}=0.
\end{equation}
The fuction must not depend on $\epsilon$. It would be better if $f(n):\mathbb{N}\rightarrow (0,1]$, but is not as important since I am interested mostly in the asymptotic behavior of the sequence. Could anyone provide an example of such a function? Thank you very much!

Comment: $f(n)=1/n^{\epsilon ^2/2}$ ?

Comment: I think I need to edit the question. The function cannot be a function of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Then use $f(n) = 1 / \log n$.

Comment: You are right I think this works!

Comment: For the proof see: [Proving $n^\epsilon>\log(n)$
for sufficiently large $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242083/proving-n-epsilon-logn-for-sufficiently-large-n).

Comment: I think I can show it with De L'hospital's rule